# Incorrect displaying items in RecyclerView while scrolling

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

Could you please assist in following issue:

I have incorrect displaying items in my messenger app.

My layout for items:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    app:cardElevation="0dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/message_my_message"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/message_your_message"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            />

</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

My layout for dialog activity:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".DialogActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/dialog_appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AnonymousAd.AppBarOverlay">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/dialog_app_bar"
            layout="@layout/app_bar_layout"
            >

        </include>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>



        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/dialog_send"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:contentDescription="TODO"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_send"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            app:fabSize="mini"
            tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/dialog_attach"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:contentDescription="TODO"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_attach"
            app:fabSize="mini"
            tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/dialog_gift"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:contentDescription="TODO"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_gift"
            app:fabSize="mini"
            tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/dialog_message"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/dialog_send"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/dialog_gift"
            android:autofillHints=""
            android:backgroundTint="@color/teal_700"
            android:hint="@string/dialog_enter_message"
            android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
            android:maxHeight="120dp"
            android:maxLength="500"
            android:minHeight="48dp"
            android:textColorHint="#757575"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/dialog_recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/dialog_message"
            android:layout_below="@+id/dialog_appbar"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:focusedByDefault="true"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />
```

Class DialogActivity

```
public class DialogActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView dialogRecyclerView;
    private LinearLayoutManager layoutManager;
    private final List<Message> messageList = new ArrayList<>();
    private MessageAdapter messageAdapter;
    private String idText;
    private String userNameText;
    private EditText dialogMessage;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private FloatingActionButton dialogSend;
    private FloatingActionButton dialogAttach;
    private String downloadedImageUrl;
    private StorageTask uploadTask;
    private Uri imageUri;
    private DatabaseReference dialogsDataBase;
    private ProgressDialog loadingBar;

    private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    private CollectionReference answersDataBase = db.collection("AnswersDataBase");
    private StorageReference imageDataBase;

    @SuppressLint("WrongViewCast")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dialog);

        idText = getIntent().getExtras().get("idText").toString();
        userNameText = getIntent().getExtras().get("userNameText").toString();

        dialogsDataBase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("DialogsDataBase").child(idText);
        imageDataBase = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("imageDataBase");

        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.dialog_app_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(userNameText);

        messageAdapter = new MessageAdapter(this, messageList);
        dialogRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.dialog_recycler_view);
        dialogRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        dialogRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        dialogRecyclerView.setAdapter(messageAdapter);

        loadingBar = new ProgressDialog(this);

        dialogMessage = findViewById(R.id.dialog_message);

        dialogAttach = findViewById(R.id.dialog_attach);

        dialogAttach.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                //startActivityForResult(intent, 438);
                someActivityResultLauncher.launch(intent);
            }
        });

        dialogMessage.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                if(dialogMessage.getText().toString().length() > 0){
                    dialogAttach.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    dialogSend.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                else {
                    dialogAttach.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    dialogSend.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
        });

        dialogSend = findViewById(R.id.dialog_send);

        dialogSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(dialogMessage.getText().toString().length() > 0){
                    answersDataBase.document(idText).update("answer", dialogMessage.getText().toString());
                    dialogsDataBase.push().setValue(new Message(Paper.book().read("userName"), dialogMessage.getText().toString(), "text"));
                    dialogMessage.setText("");
                }
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        dialogsDataBase.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {
                Message message = snapshot.getValue(Message.class);

                messageList.add(message);

                messageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                dialogRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(dialogRecyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount());
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }

    ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> someActivityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
            new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
            new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                    if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

                        loadingBar.setTitle("Sending Image");
                        loadingBar.setMessage("Please wait, we are sending that image");
                        loadingBar.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                        loadingBar.show();

                        // There are no request codes
                        Intent data = result.getData();
                        imageUri = data.getData();

                        StorageReference filePath = imageDataBase.child(System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");

                        uploadTask = filePath.putFile(imageUri);
                        uploadTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation() {
                            @Override
                            public Object then(@NonNull Task task) throws Exception {

                                if(!task.isSuccessful()){
                                    throw task.getException();
                                }

                                return filePath.getDownloadUrl();
                            }
                        }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {

                                if(task.isSuccessful()){

                                    Uri downloadUrl = task.getResult();
                                    downloadedImageUrl = downloadUrl.toString();

                                    answersDataBase.document(idText).update("answer", "Photo");
                                    dialogsDataBase.push().setValue(new Message(Paper.book().read("userName"), downloadedImageUrl, "image"));
                                    loadingBar.dismiss();
                                    recreate();
                                }

                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            });

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        messageList.clear();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        messageList.clear();
    }
}
```

Adapter class

```
public class MessageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MessageAdapter.MessageViewHolderNew> {

    private Context context;
    private List<Message> messagesList;
    private Dialog dialog;
    private String userNameString;

    public MessageAdapter(Context context, List<Message> messagesList){

        this.context = context;
        this.messagesList = messagesList;
        userNameString = Paper.book().read("userName");

    }

    public class MessageViewHolderNew extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        private TextView messageMyMessage;
        private TextView messageYourMessage;
        private ImageView messageMyImage;
        private ImageView messageYourImage;



        public MessageViewHolderNew(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            messageMyMessage = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.message_my_message);
            messageYourMessage = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.message_your_message);
            messageMyImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.message_my_image);
            messageYourImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.message_your_image);

        }
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MessageViewHolderNew onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.message_items_layout, parent, false);

        return new MessageViewHolderNew(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MessageViewHolderNew holder, int position) {

        if(messagesList.get(position).getUserName().equals(userNameString)){
            holder.messageMyMessage.setText(messagesList.get(position).getMessage());
            holder.messageMyMessage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else{
            holder.messageYourMessage.setText(messagesList.get(position).getMessage());
            holder.messageYourMessage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

   }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return messagesList.size();
    }

}
```

In this place I check user name.

```
   if(messagesList.get(position).getUserName().equals(userNameString)){
            holder.messageMyMessage.setText(messagesList.get(position).getMessage());
            holder.messageMyMessage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else{
            holder.messageYourMessage.setText(messagesList.get(position).getMessage());
            holder.messageYourMessage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
```

If user name is my name then I set message and visible to holder.messageMyMessage.
Else I set message and visible to holder.messageYourMessage.
But sometimes message and visible are set to both messages while scrolling or sent new message. .
[See attached screenshot for details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kLBp.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem's here:

```
if(messagesList.get(position).getUserName().equals(userNameString)){
    holder.messageMyMessage.setText(messagesList.get(position).getMessage());
    holder.messageMyMessage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
} else {
    holder.messageYourMessage.setText(messagesList.get(position).getMessage());
    holder.messageYourMessage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

You're only making stuff *visible*, you're never *hiding* the other thing.

So if a specific `ViewHolder` is used to display one kind of message, it'll be made visible in `onBindViewHolder`. The view in that ViewHolder's layout will be set to `VISIBLE`.

Then, if you scroll down the list and *the same ViewHolder is reused* to display the **other** kind of message, the *other* message view in the layout will be set to `VISIBLE`. **The other message view hasn't changed, it's still in the same state, VISIBLE**. So you see them both (depending on how the layout works, one might be covering the other).

When you're using a `RecyclerView`, because the `ViewHolder`s are **reused** (*recycled*) you need to set them up correctly for each item, clearing all the previous state. So in your case, for **each** message display, you have to either make it visible **or** hide it. You can't do nothing, because that can leave you with old state from the previous item it was displaying, right?

So you need to do this:

```
if(messagesList.get(position).getUserName().equals(userNameString)){
    holder.messageMyMessage.setText(messagesList.get(position).getMessage());
    holder.messageMyMessage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    // now you need to make sure the other is -not- visible!
    holder.messageYourMessage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
} else {
    holder.messageYourMessage.setText(messagesList.get(position).getMessage());
    holder.messageYourMessage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    // same thing - explicitly hide the other one, assume it could be visible
    holder.messageMyMessage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

This is the number one thing you need to do with a `RecyclerView` - in `onBindViewHolder`, *always* set up *everything* that can change depending on the item. Assume it has old data or the wrong thing set, and explicitly initialise everything. It's like a whiteboard - when you start using it you need to clean it, because maybe there's some old stuff on there